# Graphics glitches after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, upgrade, amd-graphics, 19.04, amdgpu

After upgrading to ubuntu 19.04 i experience constant graphics glitches mostly in the form of flashing horizontal Lines.

My setup:
CPU: Ryzen 2660
GPU: Radeon rx 570
OS: Ubuntu 19.04
GPU driver: amdgpu/mesa
DE: KDE Plasma 5.15.4

What I tried:

- starting gnome on wayland
  Result: same glitches
  -> X11 is nat the cause of the problem.
- running 3D Applications
  Result: mixed. I saw no glitches while running UNIGINE Superposition but I saw a few in Kerbal Space Program
  -> these should use mesa instead of amdgpu. so maybe amdgpu is the cause.
- using the terminal
  Result: still glitches
  -> the problem is something the Virtual Terminal and window servers have in common.
- taking a screencapture
  Result: no glitches on the capture
  -> XServer returns correct image
- booting an old version of Kubuntu
  Result: no glitches
  -> it's not a hardware defect

What I didnt try:

- up/downgrading amdgpu
  Why: I dont know exactly how and i dont want to brake anything

It seems to me as if the whole thing is driver-related. 
Any ideas on how to work around this and where to report the bug?